# Sonarqube 7.9.1 community troubleshooting

Tags: sonarqube

I’m trying to setup SonarQube 7.9.1 community edition with postgres on centos 7 but when I start the service, it fails.

I want to setup SonarQube with postgres on centos 7 but I can’t. I already tried to setup with docker and I get same result. The only way to start SonarQube is with H2 embebed but it works just for testing purpose.

This is the only error that log shows

```
2019.07.17 05:52:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.07.17 05:52:11 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.07.17 05:52:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.07.17 05:52:12 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.07.17 05:52:12 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.07.17 05:52:12 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
2019.07.17 05:52:19 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
2019.07.17 05:52:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.07.17 05:52:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

I don’t know why the service died but I hope to setup the service with postgres.

Comment: If you need to run this for **WSL2** then open power shell `wsl.exe -u root` , execute the command `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`,  `exit` - Recreate the docker images. Viola.

Answer (score 17):

**Error:**

```
loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin] ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144].
```

**Solution:**

Elasticsearch uses a MMap FS directory to store its indices. The default operating system limits on mmap counts is possibly to be too low, which may result in out of memory exceptions. Enter the below command to increase virtual memory value using sudo privileges,

```
$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
========================================
```

Output:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

To set value permanently, update the vm.max_map_count value in /etc/sysctl.conf. To verify after rebooting,

```
$ sysctl vm.max_map_count
```

Comment: Does this need to be run within the container or on the host?

Comment: You have to add where you have installed sonarqube.

Comment: I have tested and that is not true.... you need to run this command on the **docker host** and **not within the container where sonarqube is installed**.

Comment: Set it on the host. And don't forget to `sysctl --system` or reboot

Comment: If you need to run this for **WSL2** then open power shell `wsl.exe -u root` , execute the command, `exit` - Recreate the images. Viola.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using docker o docker-compose, you must first type `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` with root privileges. Or `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` in host machine, then you start a **new** container (must be new, restart not work), so when it begin take the configuration from the host

Answer (score 2):

The provided answers show how you can set the values on the host system.

My answer shows how you can set the values in an kubernetes init container, if you can't set system values on the host system itself.

This solution is taken from the [sonarqube helm chart](https://github.com/oteemo/charts).
If you are using helm you might want to use the sonarqube helm chart itself, which includes the solution already.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-sonarqube-init-sysctl
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
data:
  init_sysctl.sh: |-
    if [[ "$(sysctl -n vm.max_map_count)" -lt 524288 ]]; then
      sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
    fi
    if [[ "$(sysctl -n fs.file-max)" -lt 131072 ]]; then
      sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072
    fi
    if [[ "$(ulimit -n)" != "unlimited" ]]; then
      if [[ "$(ulimit -n)" -lt 131072 ]]; then
        echo "ulimit -n 131072"
        ulimit -n 131072
      fi
    fi
    if [[ "$(ulimit -u)" != "unlimited" ]]; then
      if [[ "$(ulimit -u)" -lt 8192 ]]; then
        echo "ulimit -u 8192"
        ulimit -u 8192
      fi
    fi
---
...
  initContainers:
    - name: init-sysctl
      image: busybox:1.32
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      resources:
        {}
      command: ["sh",
                "-e",
                "/tmp/scripts/init_sysctl.sh"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: init-sysctl
          mountPath: /tmp/scripts/
  containers:
    - name: sonarqube
      image: sonarqube:...
...
  volumes:
    - name: init-sysctl
      configMap:
        name: sonarqube-sonarqube-init-sysctl
        items:
          - key: init_sysctl.sh
            path: init_sysctl.sh
    - name: sonar-data
```

**Remark**

This answer does not exactly apply to the question, but gives a solution to the same problem when running sonarqube in kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it out and it **finally works again** with Version `9.4-community`

I set the variable `SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE` to true.

**Bicep (ARM):**

```
resource siteName_appsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2020-06-01' = {
 parent: siteName_resource
 name: 'appsettings'
 properties: {
  SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL: 'xyz'
  SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME: 'xyz'
  SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD: 'xyz'
  SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE: 'true' // <--
  'sonar.path.data': '/home/sonarqube/data' 
 }
}
```

see also: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/pull/12519

Answer (score 1):

Your system isn't allowed to map enough memory for each process according to the line

> [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Run the following command before attempting to start SonarQube or issuing your `docker compose` command:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Was it the same error, or a slightly different one? I'd expect you to also get an error about `fs.file-max` if you've not configured a value for fs.file-max` directly but the `vm.max_map` setting was applied. If it's the same error, could you provide the output of running `sysctl vm.max_map_count` please?

Comment: No, it was the same error:
``` 
2019.07.17 21:23:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.07.17 21:23:41 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
2019.07.17 21:23:49 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of running `sysctl vm.max_map_count` please?

Comment: This is the output:
```
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

Comment: Ah, it is the file descriptors the second warning was giving you. You'll need to run `sysctl -w fs.file-max=65535` to fix that second error.

Comment: were you able to fix the issue... I am getting this issue  [1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]  and eneb have increased FD still not sure why it says 4096. from where this is comming

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not provide a solution but it may shed some light on why some people might not be able to get elsaticsearch up and running on their virtual server.

I have the same problem, but I am not able to change the value `vm.max_map_count`. I receive the error when running `sysctl --system` and adding `vm.max_map_count=262144` into file `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-elasticsearch.conf`

`* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-elasticsearch.conf ...
sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`

After investing some time it turns out that my virtual CentOS7 server is running on WSL. And WSL does not support setting of all kernel parameters, and `vm.max_map_count` is one of it (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3126#issuecomment-396271872).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add args in your manifest of k8s

> -Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false

for example:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - image: sonarqube:8.8-community
      args:
        - -Dsonar.web.context=/sonar
        - -Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AppService or other Docker service, most probably is that you can't change de host OS values with sysctl

In that case, you can change the ElasticSearch configuration, disabling memory mapping, setting this variable in the java execution of SonarQube, this variable will pass it's value as a Java parameter when launching ElasticSearch:

```
-Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false
```

SonarCube will launch ElasticSearch with this param

```
-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false
```

NOTE: For ElasticSearch version < V8.x use node.store.allow_mmapfs instead